# What does DataAccessor do in tfx?

Tags: tensorflow, tensorflow-datasets, tfx

I'm reading the tfx [tutorials](https://www.tensorflow.org/tfx/tutorials), which all uses the `DataAccessor` to load data. The code looks something like this:

```py
  return data_accessor.tf_dataset_factory(
      file_pattern,
      tfxio.TensorFlowDatasetOptions(
          batch_size=batch_size, label_key=_LABEL_KEY),
      schema=schema).repeat()
```

This makes sense at a highlevel for the tutorials but I can't find relevant documentations when I dug deeper.
The `tf_dataset_factory` function take a [`tfxio.TensorFlowDatasetOptions`](https://www.tensorflow.org/tfx/tfx_bsl/api_docs/python/tfx_bsl/public/tfxio/TensorFlowDatasetOptions) argument and so from the args description I'm deducing that class has some type of effect similar to:

```py
dataset = tfds.load() # load data
dataset = dataset.batch(batch_size) # batch data
dataset = dataset.shuffle() # shuffle data
dataset = dataset.prefetch() # prefetch data
```

But it's not clear to me in what order this is applied (if it matters) and how I can manipulate the dataset in details. For example, I want to apply `Dataset.cache()` but it's not clear to me whether if applying `cache()` after the `tf_dataset_factory` makes sense.

Another example of what I don't understand is whether if `DataAccessor` has predefined distributed training support. i.e. do I need to multiply `batch_size` by `strategy.num_replicas_in_sync`? Because the distributed training tutorials makes a clear statement on doing that but the tfx tutorials don't even mention it, so to me it's a 50/50 whether if the `num_replicas_in_sync` is already compensated for.

Wondering if anyone else are in the same shoes or have better ideas?

Answer (score -1):

Looking through the [documentations](https://github.com/tensorflow/tfx/blob/r1.7.0/tfx/components/trainer/fn_args_utils.py), `DataAccessor` seems to be a utility wrapper around a `tf.data.Dataset` factory. The object that is returned is an instance of `tf.data.Dataset` - so any subsequent methods that apply to a normal `Dataset` object are valid here too.

I cant comment on the distributed training support and it is not documented anywhere as you rightly pointed out